# Text() inside of my if statement changes the outcome of the if statement?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

Here is a snippet of code I am working with:

```swift
struct FindFriendsResultsList: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var view_model: CreateEventViewModel
    @State private var followAll: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $followAll) {
                Text("Follow all friends")
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                   ForEach(self.view_model.contact_list_decoded["contacts"] ?? [], id: \.self) { user in
                       VStack {
                            if self.followAll == true {
                                UserRow(user: user, action: "Success")
                            }
                            else {
                                UserRow(user: user)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The weirdness is that the `if self.followAll == true` conditional never equals true unless I include `Text(String(self.followAll))` within the conditional. Then the toggle works as expected. This looks like:

```swift
if self.followAll == true {
    Text(String(self.followAll))
    UserRow(user: user, action: "Success")
}
else {
    UserRow(user: user)
}
```

I just don't want to include `Text(String(self.followAll))` and would prefer for this conditional to work with only the UserRow inside.

EDIT: Here's a bit more code. I am stripping any UI from this and trying to provide as specific of an example as possible.:

```swift
struct UserRow: View {
    @State var action: String = "AddFriend"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if action == "AddFriend" {
                Image("addfriendicon")
            }
            else if action == "Success" {
                Image("Successicon")
            } 
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post some more context?  Maybe the full body of the view, or the whole view itself?

Comment: Sure @kid_x I just updated the post to try to showcase exactly what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
   ForEach(self.view_model.contact_list_decoded["contacts"] ?? [], id: \.self) { user in
         UserRow(user: user, follow: self.followAll) // << move decision inside
    }
```

and

```
struct UserRow: View {
    let user: YOUR_USER_TYPE
    let follow: Bool           // if more needed, make enum
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if follow {
                Image("Successicon")
            } else {
                Image("addfriendicon")
            }
        }
    }
}
```